# What is the value of the 2nd order tensor $\delta_{ii}$?

Tags: tensors

According to Dr. Robert Hunt's [lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/reh10/lectures/nst-mmii-chapter3.pdf)(which are great!), it is not 1 (top of page 4) and uses formulas as such. Why would the kronecker delta function $\delta_{ii}$ not be 1? According to Hobson, Riley, Bence it is 1 and uses formulas as such:

---

[image]

Comment: (Ab)using Einstein's notation $\delta_{ii} = \sum_i \delta_{ii} = \mbox{ dimension of space}$

Comment: $\delta_{ii}$ is typically reserved for the kroenecker delta not the dirac delta function.

Comment: oops, I think I meant the kronecker delta function.

Comment: not the one with the integral equal to one, the one with the reversal of indices

Comment: So it equals n dimensions and not zero?

Comment: You can represent $\delta_{ij}$ as a $nxn$ identity matrix, where $n$ is the dimension. $\delta_{ii}$ is then just the $tr(I)$.

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to my second question below or should I create a second post? Why then, is eq 26.31=+1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to both Hunt and everybody else,

$$
\delta_{ij} = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 1 & \mbox {if } i=j
\\0 & \mbox{otherwise}
 \end{array} \right.
$$

Your confusion arises because $\delta_{ii}$ is not a rank 2 tensor, it is a scalar -- the summation convention makes this a sum over values of $i$.
$$
\delta_{ii} = d
$$
where $d$ is the dmension of the space; in three dimensions 
$$\delta_{ii} = \delta_{11}+\delta_{22}+\delta_{33} = 1+1+1 = 3$$

Comment: Why is 26.30 equal to 1? What is $\delta_{ii}\delta_{jj}-\delta_{jl}\delta_{jl}$ $$n \times n-n$$?